# headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding on every scroll and making api call to the server how to stop it

Tags: flutter, dart

**headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding the ui and making api call every time how to stop it?
When i scroll to the bottom and back to top headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding!
Thanks in advance to all!**

headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding the ui and making api call every time how to stop it?
When i scroll to the bottom and back to top headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding!
Thanks in advance to all!
headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding the ui and making api call every time how to stop it?
When i scroll to the bottom and back to top headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding!
Thanks in advance to all!headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding the ui and making api call every time how to stop it?
When i scroll to the bottom and back to top headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding!
Thanks in advance to all!headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding the ui and making api call every time how to stop it?
When i scroll to the bottom and back to top headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding!
Thanks in advance to all!headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding the ui and making api call every time how to stop it?
When i scroll to the bottom and back to top headerSliverBuilder is rebuilding!
Thanks in advance to all!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart';

/// constants
import '/utils/constants.dart';

/// global widgets
import '../ScrollList/ScrollList.dart';
import '../../components/app_widgets.dart';

/// local widgets
import './components/HomeFilter.dart';
import './components/TopBarTitle.dart';

/// lectures, articles, groups
import './components/Lecture/LecturesPart.dart';
import './components/Articles/ArticlesPart.dart';
import './components/Groups/GroupsPart.dart';

class MainCollapsingToolbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainCollapsingToolbarState createState() => _MainCollapsingToolbarState();
}

class _MainCollapsingToolbarState extends State<MainCollapsingToolbar> {
  ScrollController _scrollController=new ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[

              SliverCustomAppBarWidgets(),
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                  TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.black87,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                    tabs: tabs,
                  ),
                ),
                pinned: true,
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [

              LecturesPart(),
              ArticlesPart(),
              GroupsPart(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class SliverCustomAppBarWidgets extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverCustomAppBarWidgets({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SliverCustomAppBarWidgetsState createState() => _SliverCustomAppBarWidgetsState();
}

class _SliverCustomAppBarWidgetsState extends State<SliverCustomAppBarWidgets> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SliverCustomAppBarWidgets>{
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final CustomSliverAppBar = ListView(
      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
      children: [
        AppWidgets.appBar(context),
        TopBarTitle(),
        ScrollCentersList(),
        HomeFilter()
      ],
    );

    return SliverAppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 260,
      backgroundColor: COLOR_WHITE,
      floating: false,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: CustomSliverAppBar,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);
  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      child: _tabBar,
      color: COLOR_WHITE,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

const tabs = [
  Tab(text: 'Lectures',),
  Tab(text: 'Articles',),
  Tab(text: 'Groups',)
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)

Which will give you the ability to control your widget rebuild based on a condition you provide. If you don't want to rebuild your widget at all, you could just set that condition to be always true.

Comment: How did you implement it?. Every widget that wants to stay alive while off-screen should inherit the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin.

Comment: `headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[

              SliverCustomAppBarWidgets(),
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                  TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.black87,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                    tabs: tabs,
                  ),
                ),
                pinned: true,
              ),
            ];
          },    `      This part is rebuilding ! how should i implement here ? thanks in advance